# json.dump lead to json.decoder.JSONDecodeError when json.load(f)

Tags: python, json

After adding following code, the json.dump will dump with malformed json after few loop. It is weird that this error doesn't raised immediately, the error is raised after few loops.

```
if len(data) > 30:
    data.pop(0)
```

I receive the following error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 34 column 1 (char 1261)
```

Part of my code:

```
with open(file_to_open, "r+", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        if title not in data:
            r = requests.post(url=url, data=parameters)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                message = f"{actor} - {title} is downloading"
                print(message)
                push_notification(message)
                data.append(title)
                if len(data) > 30:
                    data.pop(0)
                f.seek(0)
                json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

What's causing the problem? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're partially overwriting the file…? You should truncate the file before or after overwriting it, but since you're opening it in reading mode, that's not automatically happening.

Comment: If the new data is shorter than the old data it will leave some cruft at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by simply adding `f.truncate()` at the end:

```
json.dump(data, f, ...)
f.truncate()
```

If you ever run into such a problem again, simply opening the file in a text editor should make the problem immediately obvious.

The issue that you are facing is that, if the JSON form of the new data is shorter, some data will be left. Suppose your data starts like this:

```
{"test": "alphabeta"}
```

Then you try to overwrite it with this:

```
{"test": "alpha"}
```

Writing it to the open file will give the following result:

```
{"test": "alpha"}ta"}
```

Which is obviously not valid JSON. `.truncate()` will remove all data from a file after the cursor position.

As for why it happens sometimes, the length of the data will depend on the exact titles of the books etc and will vary randomly. It will only fail if the result is shorter than the previous result, which will be roughly half the time.

Without `data.pop()` the size of the data will only ever grow, so there will never be a situation where the new JSON is shorter.

Comment: I did open the file to see. But not sure why this happening. Can you explain what does the f.truncate do? why is this only happen after few loop? Why this error only arise after adding the data.pop(0)?

Comment: I added some explanation